# I'm getting 0 results in this query. What am I doing wrong? (Android)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite on Android. These are my three tables:

```
String query = "create table " + TABLE_PERSON + " (" +
            PERSON_COL_ID + "  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            PERSON_COL_NAME + " text, " +
            PERSON_COL_SEX + " text CHECK (" + PERSON_COL_SEX + " IN ('M', 'F'))" +
            ");";
db.execSQL(query);

query = "create table " + TABLE_CONCEPT + " (" +
            CONCEPT_COL_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            CONCEPT_COL_NAME + " text, " +
            CONCEPT_COL_DATE + " text " +
            ");";
db.execSQL(query);

query = "create table " + TABLE_DEBT + " (" +
            DEBT_COL_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            DEBT_COL_CONCEPT + " integer REFERENCES " + TABLE_CONCEPT + ", " +
            DEBT_COL_CREDITOR + " integer REFERENCES " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
            DEBT_COL_DEBTOR + " integer REFERENCES " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
            DEBT_COL_ORIGAMT + " integer, " +
            DEBT_COL_PAIDSOFAR + " integer, " +
            DEBT_COL_DATEREPAID + " text" +
            ");";
db.execSQL(query);
```

After inserting 3 persons, 2 concepts and 1 debt, I am getting 0 results after making the following query:

```
  Cursor cur = databaseHelper.getDebtsByConcept(0);
```

Where the query carried out is the following:

```
public Cursor getDebtsByConcept(int conceptID) {
     String query = "select con.name, per1.name, per2.name, deb.origamt, deb.paidsofar, deb.daterepaid" +
            " from " +
            TABLE_PERSON + " per1, " + TABLE_PERSON + " per2, " +  TABLE_CONCEPT + " con, " + TABLE_DEBT + " deb" +
            " where deb.concept = " + conceptID +
            " and con.id = deb.concept " +
            " and per1.id = deb.creditorID" +
            " and per2.id = deb.debtorID;";

     Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
     return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there will not be any entry in database with `conecptID` with value 0, reason for the same is that you have declared `conceptID` in `concept table` as `Integer Auto Increment` so when you insert first record value will be conceptId value will be `1`,

Can you try passing 1 in your query, and just to check initially try and fetch all the records from database using `select * from ....`

Comment: Searching with conceptID == 1 also returns 0 entries.

Doing "select * from debts" returns one entry (the only one that there is):
(col 0)->1, (col 1)->0, (col 2)->0, (col 3)->0, (col 4)->10000, (col 5)->100, (col 6)->xxx,

Comment: there seems to be some mismatch in the data, can you do `select * from ..` other tables and see what results you are getting ?

Comment: I think it's obvious what's happening. The foreign keys in the debts table point nowhere:

>>DEBTS<<
id: 1, concept: 0, creditorID: 0, debtorID: 0, origamt: 10000, paidsofar: 100, daterepaid: date, 

>>PERSONS<<
id: 1, name: Ismael, sex: M, 
id: 2, name: Martyna, sex: F, 
id: 3, name: Tadzio, sex: M, 

>>CONCEPTS<<
id: 1, name: excursion, date: date, 
id: 2, name: party, date: date,

Comment: I solved it finally. Thank you. The problem was the most obvious one.